# To apply onclickListener on GridView in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I have taken an Grid an added 9 images in it and onclick of any Image i am trying to navigate on some page.But i am not able to set a listener on GridField manager .i tried the following code :

```
            grid.add(bmp1);
    grid.add(bmp2);
    grid.add(bmp3);
    grid.add(bmp4);
    grid.add(bmp5);

    grid.setChangeListener(new fieldChangeListener());
    add(grid);
}
class fieldChangeListener implements FieldChangeListener{


    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside Method : "+field.getAccessibleContext());
        if(field==bmp1){
            Dialog.alert("1 is clicked");
        }
        if(field==bmp2){
            Dialog.alert("2 is clicked");
        }
        if(field==bmp3){
            Dialog.alert("3 is clicked");
        }
        if(field==bmp4){
            Dialog.alert("4 is clicked");
        }
        if(field==bmp5){
            Dialog.alert("5 is clicked");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Manager` is used to arrange fields, it is not receiving its own focus and clicks(normally ).use `Fields` to receive focus and clicks unless you have a good reason to change the behavior.

If you want to make a `Manager` a click effect then You will create a custom manager and override the `navigationClick` Methode.

Comment: Can you post a small sample code on how to override the Manager.
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you can simply replace  grid.setChangeListener(new fieldChangeListener()); by bmp1.setChangeListener(new fieldChangeListener()); bmp2.setChangeListener(new fieldChangeListener());... etc.. No need of custom manager.. to create sustom manager see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597084/blackberry-creating-a-custom-field-to-use-with-verticalfieldmanager-to-replicat